# Finding the values of the coefficients $a,b,c$ in the curve $y=ax^2+bx+c$.

Tags: calculus, quadratics

The curve $y=ax^2+bx+c$ crosses the $y$-axis at the point $(0,3)$ and has a stationary point at $(1,2)$. Find the value of $a$, $b$ and $c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

By the givens we can easily find that

- for crossing $y$ at $(0,3) \implies 3=a\cdot 0^2+b\cdot 0+c$
- stationary point at $(1,2) \implies y'(1)=0\implies 2a\cdot 1+b=0$
- for crossing at $(1,2) \implies 2=a\cdot 1^2+b\cdot 1+c$

then solve the system of three equations to find $a,b, c$.

Comment: Can you give me a little explanation about the "stationary point"? Please

Comment: @user9602923 By definition of stationary point we have that the derivative at that point is equal to zero then $y'(x)=2ax+b=0$ for $x=1$.

Comment: @user9602923 Let try to solve the system and show your result, I will look to that for check!

Comment: Oh, okay. So I'm expected to always find the derivative of $y$ when at stationary point.?

Comment: @user9602923 Yes for general functions. In this case since it is a parabola, if you were not aware about derivatives, you can use the fact the the coordinate for the vertex (that is the unique stationary point for a parabola) is located at $x=-b/2a=1\implies 2a+b=0$ that is precisely the condition found by the derivative.

Comment: Oh, that's why I wasn't understanding what @Delta-u said. But I think I get it now $x=-b/2a$. Thanks gimusi. Let me try it out and see how it goes.

Comment: I'm quite sure that taken the derivative is much more easier to me coz that's what I'm familiar with.

Comment: @user9602923 ok then proceed in this way!

Answer (score 1):

@Gimusi, here... 
$y=ax^2+bx+c$
At point (0,3),
We have $3=a•0^2+b(0)+c$
=> **3=c**

At stationary point (1,2)...we takes the derivative of "y"..and equate it to zero 
$=> y^1=2ax + b = 0$
There4,
$2ax + b = 0$ but x=1
$2a + b =0.....(1)$
And also, at point (1,2)
We have, 
$2=a+b+3$ since c=3.
$=>a+b=-1.......(2)$
$(1)-(2)$
:•a=1
Put a=1 into (2)...
Then b=-2
Therefore, 
a=1,b=-2 and c=3.
So,
$y=x^2-2x+3$.

I'm a right?

Comment: Yes it’s correct how you can check directly on your final result. Well done! Bye

Comment: Thanks to you. I'm much grateful

Comment: You are welcome! Only for information, why did you unaccepted my answer? It is not a problem of course and the choice is completely up to you. I ask to understand how I we can make my answers more clear in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Ah no, I guess it was unexpectedly done, I mean, unknowingly.... I like your answer and it even gives me more understanding.

Comment: Ahhhhh I was indeed wondering were was my fault :) Anyway really it is not a problem, you are the only which can choose the aswer to accept! But if it was unexpectedly done I'm happy now it is clear. Thanks! Bye

Comment: Can't I reaccept it?

Comment: Yes now it is ok! and you can change whenever you want!

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=a x^2 + b x +c$. The value at $x=0$ give $c=f(0)$ and the stationary point is at $1=x_0=-\frac{b}{2a}$ with value $2=a x_0^2 +b x_0 +c$.

That give you as set of $3$ linear equations and $3$ unknowns.

Comment: Thanks Delta-u.